# Microsoft Pluton Security Chip - Specs and API?

Tags: windows, tpm, microsoft

Microsoft introduced a new security chip dubbed [Pluton](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2020/11/17/meet-the-microsoft-pluton-processor-the-security-chip-designed-for-the-future-of-windows-pcs/) that is ought to become mandatory for systems running Windows (11 and forward).

AMD has already implemented or is about to implement the chip as part of the [Ryzen processors](https://community.amd.com/t5/corporate/amd-to-integrate-microsoft-pluton-security-processor-to-future/ba-p/422357)

It has also been mentioned that Pluton builds upon TPM 2.0. There is a detailled spcification of TPM 2.0 by the Trusted Computing Group (TCG), including definitions for the API.

However I was unable to find any information about Pluton at all.

Is there a technical specification of Pluton available? Is there a programming API available? Are there plans to create and release such information, or does it seem to be a proprietary technology where outsiders won't have access to, contrasting the approach that the TCG has taken?

Comment: I was going to point you towards [i.MX 8ULP-CS](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/arm-processors/i-mx-applications-processors/i-mx-8-processors/i-mx-8ulp-cs-cloud-secured-applications-processors:i.MX8ULP-CS), since NXP is *usually* fairly open with their documentation, but it does not seem to be the case this time, although it might be due to it's preproduction status.

Comment: Also, a slight nitpick: Pluton seems to be an [IP core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_intellectual_property_core) rather than a chip - something that vendors integrate directly into their SoCs.

Comment: It sounds like this is just an fTPM (firmware TPM) with some extra features like facial recognition.